# Reducing the number of queries from 2 to 1

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is it possible to use 1 query instead 2? Or this way is better? (for speed)

```
<?
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT name,url,id FROM gallery") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($q1) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {   
    echo 'IMAGES FROM '.$row['name'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    //second query for each gallery
    $imgq = mysql_query("SELECT img  FROM img WHERE ids=" . $id . " ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($img = mysql_fetch_array($imgq)) {
      ?><img src="<?=$img['img'];?>"><?
    } //multiple images
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't simply a difference between executing 1 query and 2 queries... its a difference between 1 query and 1+n queries, where n is the number of results returned by the first query. So a single query is definitely more efficient

Answer (score 4):

You need a Join to bring this back in one query.

```
SELECT name,url,id,img
FROM gallery g
JOIN img i ON i.ids=g.id
```

This is more efficient as it reduces the number of requests and table accesses you are making.

It does mean that you will be bringing back repeated rows with `name,url,id` but the effect of this will likely be minimal.